# Select a row in Devxpress datagrid using a button (C#)

Tags: c#, datagrid, devexpress, xtragrid

I have this Devexpress 13 Xtragrid.gridcontrol and I can find the row that is selected, using this code:

```
int[] selRows = ((Gridview))grdMygrid.Mainview).GetSelectedRows();
DataRowView selRow (DataRowView)(((Gridview)grdMyView.MainView).GetRow(selRows[0]));
int SelectedIndex = selRows[0];
```

Now, this works like a charm... Only I added some navigation buttons with which I want to be able to scroll through the gridcontrol. (next, previous, last, first)

I can't seem to set the row in code. Somebody here have an idea on how to accomplish this?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
myGrid.SelectedRow = SelectedIndex();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the FocusedRowHandle of the main view of your grid.

If you have named it ViewMain (as i usually do) you may :

```
ViewMain.FocusedRowHandle = SelectedIndex();
```

or you may cast the MainView property of your grid to GridView and set the FocusedRowHandle property:

```
((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)myGrid.MainView).FocusedRowHandle = SelectedIndex();
```